# rospy.loginfo on remote machine

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, remote

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I launched a package on a remote machine, the rospy.loginfo messages of that package do not show up on my local machine that is running the roscore and initiated the roslaunch. Is there some modification to the rospy.loginfo that needs to be done to get it to send the log to the local machine?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282058/rospy.loginfo-on-remote-machine/) by [mdturner32](https://answers.ros.org/users/33389/mdturner32/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried using rqt_console?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-08**:
Exactly. @mdturner32: what you see in the console is only output printed by the processes that were started in that console. You'll need to use different tools (such as `rqt_console` mentioned by @ahendrix) for everything else.

**Comment by [mdturner32](https://answers.ros.org/users/33389/mdturner32/) on 2018-03-26**:
Sorry for the very late response. But just wanted to update and say thanks, I did use rqt_console and it worked for me great. Appreciate the advice

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-27**:
@mdturner32: if @ahendrix's answer answered your question, then please mark the question as answered by ticking the checkmark to the left of it.